# Can I start working on Aragon Client and then migrate to aragonOSx when the new protocol comes out?

Tags: solidity, dao, protocol, migration

I have an idea I want to get started with building my own custom DAO, but I saw there was a new aragonOS protocol coming out - so I want to make sure I'm not working on a deprecating product.

Do you recommend getting started using the existing product and then migrating to when the new one is out? Or should I wait? Will the old aragonOS get deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

The Aragon team is working on a migration process, but upon launch, aragonOS DAOs will not be able to easily migrate into aragonOSx.

A current possible solution is to transfer over the assets to a new aragonOSx DAO and start releasing proposals and voting there.